# Can a MS-VAR(1) be discretized to a Markov-chain the same way a VAR(1) has a discrete approximation?

Tags: macroeconomics, time-series, markov-chain

It is well known via Tauchen (1986) that a VAR(1) process can be approximately fairly well (in the absence of persistence) by a discrete Markov-chain if the innovation is distributed standard normal.

Can a MS-VAR(1) be approximated in the same manner?